# angular2 beta9: json pipe broken by Promise?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Using angular 2 beta 9.

If you open the plnkr in [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/6OXyaTOCPLcjGRuNaze0?p=preview) and uncomment the html with the json pipe you will see that the code is broken and you will see some error in the console.

I'm copying the code here for convenience.

any ideas ?

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgIf} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>

      <!-- This pipe breaks the code 
      <p>data promise: {{data | json}}</p> -->

      <p>data resolved: {{data|async}}</p>
      <button (click)="clicked()">Hello Promise</button>

      <div *ngIf="data|async"> 
        <p>data: {{data | json}}</p>
        Yes, The data is resolved: {{data|async}}
      </div>

    </div>
  `,
  directives: [NgIf]

})

export class AppComponent {
  data: Promise<string>;

  constructor() {
    this.data = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve("Hello World from constrcutor ");
        }, 500)
        });
  }

  clicked() {
    this.data = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve("Clicked");
        }, 500);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: That issue with pipes is related to minification, read [#6380](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6380), you'll find a workaround that may help you (almost at the end of the issue). The other one is related to these issues [#5950](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5950), [#6005](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6005) (there are a lot issues about that). So just changed to `dev` bundles and you'll be fine.

Comment: do you mean to use angular2.js instead of angular2.min.js ? (it does not make any difference)

Comment: Here's your [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/jKQYTRwDEDQRNUkPVHvn?p=preview) fixed. I put `data | json` inside `NgIf` to avoid the `has changed` error. Note that I'm using the `angular2.dev.js` bundle. Try changing to `angular2.min.js` and see that it will throw.

Comment: Thanks Eric, that solves most of the problems. There is still something which doesn't smells well: if I add `<p>data promise: {{data | json}}</p>`, it will break the code: [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/z31cHt13dcuHDhrBc2n2?p=preview) . If you comment out the "button" block, it works... So it is related to having a button in the component...

Comment: I've just edited the post and plnkr: it is actually {{data | json}} breaking the {{data | async}}

Comment: Yes, and that's change detection. Json pipe is not breaking anything, it's not json pipe problem. You can simply put json pipe inside ngIf, like I did before to stop the error message. The other thing you can do is `{{data | async | json}}` https://plnkr.co/edit/lU33SGOlagueizzMebSW?p=preview